# How to pass a user defined table type returned from a function as a parameter to another inline function (without 'DECLARE')?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, table-valued-parameters

I'm afraid the answer to this is "NO, you can't", but since I can't find this explained anywhere I'm gonna ask anyway.

Given a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE(
    [Id]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
```

And a function that returns that type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFind]
(
    @info UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN( SELECT TOP 1 Id, Name FROM TblUsers WHERE Id = @info );
```

And another function that accepts that type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnName]
(
    @single MyType READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN( SELECT TOP 1 Name, 42 AS NextColumn, 43 AS MoreCols FROM @single );
```

Since the return value of `fnFind` fits the value that is accepted by `fnName`, I'd hoped that I could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable sot 
INNER JOIN dbo.fnName(dbo.fnFind(sot.Id)) f ON sot.Id = f.Id

-- OR using the select-syntax, since it is a table
SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable sot 
INNER JOIN dbo.fnName((SELECT * FROM dbo.fnFind(sot.Id))) f ON sot.Id = f.Id
```

Unfortunately, that syntax leads to errors. Likely, if I add it to a multi-statement script or function I can just assign it and pass it on, but if I want to use a construct like this inside an line TVF, I believe I cannot use `DECLARE` statements. So I hoped there exists some syntax to do this.

*(sorry for the simplicity of the functions above, it's just to explain the point. Currently the use is within a trigger so I can use multiple statements, but I'd like to use this inside `SELECT` statements as well, which would require this kind of "functional piping")*

**Update:** Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I know I can do it by using cursors or maybe some other magic, but since the logical table `inserted` has one-or-more rows, I cannot simply declare a variable:

Here `fnGetMatchingKey` takes a UDTT and `fnGetSearchFields` returns a table that has the same schema as that UDTT, but this syntax seems to be disallowed:

```
UPDATE TableX
SET MatchingKeyId = (SELECT TOP 1 KeyId FROM dbo.fnGetMatchingKey(wi.Id, [dbo].[fnGetSearchFields](wi.Id)))
FROM WorkItems wi
INNER JOIN inserted i
ON wi.Id= i.Id
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an inline table expression to fill a table-valued parameter. They must be assigned to variables. What you can do is `CROSS APPLY` a function and pass it columns (and with an inline TVF, the optimizer can actually do pretty well with this).

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks! I forgot about `CROSS APPLY`, I used that before but am a bit rusty on the syntax. If you've seen the `UPDATE` statement at the bottom (I updated my Q while you were typing), which is supposed to be run in a trigger, can that be applied there somehow? Feel free to post as answer :).

Comment: `UPDATE` accepts arbitrary table expressions in the `FROM`, so yes. I find updating a CTE to be more understandable than using the `FROM`, though (`WITH x AS (SELECT *, NewValue FROM TableX) UPDATE x SET Column = NewValue`, where the `SELECT` is written to produce only one row per row in `WorkItems`), since you can test the `SELECT` separately.

Comment: I don't understand the `update` at all.  `TableX` has no conditions on it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the `UPDATE` is supposed to fill a calculated persisted field for which I couldn't find a way to do it as a normal calculated field. Since it applies to everything in the `inserted` logical table, that works as a binding condition. This should work (in fact, it does work, apart from the function).

Comment: @Jeroen, I'm now thinking that `CROSS APPLY` won't help in allowing me to pass a UDTT parameter to another function. My example is misleading, sorry, I wrote `TOP 1`, but it `fnFind` returns a row set, which is then queried in the `fnName`.

Comment: This is correct; you cannot pass rowsets between functions this way. Only the outermost function can return a table. Either rewrite everything as `CROSS APPLY`s on single rows (possibly nested) or use a stored procedure. T-SQL is not a very orthogonal language and you cannot combine features at will even where this superficially seems possible; passing around rowsets in particular can be done only in very limited scenarios.

Comment: You probably could do this as an inline TVF. `DECLARE` can be simulated with `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`, and `WHILE` can be simulated with a recursive CTE, cursors can be simulated with a tally table. Most things are possible (within the bounds of a basic `SELECT` statement, no DML, `EXEC` or `CREATE`). If you [edit] and post the code for the functions we could see what can be done

Comment: A UDDT is like a class in OO languages. Just because you create 2 separate classes that contain the same members and have the same inheritance does not mean you can assign / pass / use one in place of the other. So the idea that you can pass or assign to/from the UDDT to a table of the same structure is simply not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `select`, I think you are looking for `apply`:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeOtherTable sot CROSS APPLY
     dbo.fnName(dbo.fnFind(sot.Id)) f
```

I'm not sure if you need the condition `sot.Id = f.Id`.  I'm guessing this is superfluous.

Comment: I thought this wasn't allowed: `dbo.fnName(dbo.fnFind(sot.Id))` (the inner function returning a table), but I'll try it.

Comment: @Abel . . . It is allowed with `apply`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5175cfdd95914a43d42dd936b320611b.